# faster and efficient way (on a large dataframe with millions of rows) to pull row closest to the supplied timestamp(s)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, timestamp

Am trying to pull data from a dataframe that has timestamp next closest to the ones i supply (via a list)

The below works fine, however it is extremely slow, as it pulls one record as a df.
Can i check with you a faster and efficient way, given i have 100s of thousand rows in the dataframe to work on.

```
entrytimes = df_2['timestamp_col'][df_2['Entry']==-1]
closest_df3_entries = [] 
for i in entrytimes:
    closest_df3_entries.append(df_1.loc[[(abs(df_1.iloc[:, 2]-entrytimes[i])).idxmin()]])
```

Comment: `df_1.iloc[:, 2]` can be simplified to `df_1[2]`

Comment: Sorry just edited my question a bit

Comment: Why did you remove the copyable code?

Comment: Thanks, but how can we make it faster ?